# Modify this SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT K.OBJECT_ID, K.`TYPE`
FROM KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS K
WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN') 
GROUP BY K.OBJECT_ID
HAVING count(K.OBJECT_ID) = 2;
```

on a table such as this

```
OBJECT_ID   TYPE
1              ISSN
1              ISBN
2              ISSN
2              ISSN
```

I need the result to show **both** the objects with number 1 because they have both ISSN and ISBN but not the rows with object ID is number 2 because they are both ISSN.

currently my query would show the first record (only once) and it will also show the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS
where OBJECT_ID in 
(
    SELECT K.OBJECT_ID
    FROM KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS K
    WHERE K.`TYPE` IN ('ISSN', 'ISBN') 
    GROUP BY K.OBJECT_ID
    HAVING count(distinct K.OBJECT_ID) = 2
)
```

Comment: I used this answer in combination with

    HAVING count(DISTINCT K.`TYPE`) = 2 

and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `group by` is the simplest way.  I think `exists` is:

```
select k.*
from KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS k
where exists (select 1
              from KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS k2
              where k.object_id = k2.object_id and
                    k.type <> k2.type
             );
```

EDIT:  If there are other types:

```
select k.*
from KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS k
where k.type in ('ISSN', 'ISBN') and
      exists (select 1
              from KB_OBJECT_IDENTIFIERS k2
              where k2.object_id = k.object_id and
                    k2.type in ('ISSN', 'ISBN') and
                    k2.type <> k.type
             );
```

Comment: It's close but doesn't solve the issue, because I need specifically ISSN and ISBN So if there were other types I don't want them to be selected.

Comment: @yankel . . . The query is easily modified to support that.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT in Count

```
HAVING count(DISTINCT K.`TYPE`) = 2
```